# How to pass a parameter to the "3G" in ChromeDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How to pass a parameter to the "3G" in ChromeDriver and can it be done?

Screenshot
https://prnt.sc/h2aqf4

```
Map<string, string> mobileEmulation = new hashmap<string, string>();
mobileEmulation.put("devicename", "iPhone 6");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
wd = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

selenium 3.6.0, ChromeDriver-2.33

P/S Sorry, my English is bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `networkThrottle` option also get detailed information from url which i shared below.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=984#c6

Comment: mobileEmulation.put("networkThrottling","Fast 3G");  - not working.

Comment: Presets:

network_throttle = { "networkName": "Good 3G" }
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("networkThrottle", network_throttle)

Customized:

network_throttle = { "networkConditions": { "downloadThroughput": 10, "uploadThroughput": 1, "latency": 500} }
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("networkThrottle", network_throttle)

or

network_throttle = { "networkConditions": { "throughput": 10, "latency": 500} }
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("networkThrottle", network_throttle)    - That it is impossible to apply this code. How to do it?

Comment: not working  Map<String, String> networkThrottle = new HashMap<String, String>();
        networkThrottle.put("networkName","Fast 3G");
        options.setExperimentalOption("networkThrottle", networkThrottle);

Comment: I think it is implemented on selenium library. If you try below code it should be work. 
```driver.setNetworkConnection(ConnectionType.DATA);```

2G, 3G, 4G, LTE are not implemented yet.
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/mobile/NetworkConnection.java

Comment: As I understand it, this is not yet implemented? Right?

Comment: 2G, 3G, 4G, LTE are not yet implemented. But DATA is implemented.